# MySQL syntax error in login.php file

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mamp

I am constructing a simple login php page. 
The problem is, whatever I put as username or password, I get back this syntax error:

*"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '￼   ￼AND user.password = ''' at line 4"*

I don't seem to understand what's wrong, even though I searched in google for similar problems. I use MAMP (if that helps).
Can someone please help me?

My check.php file goes like this:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$hostname = "localhost"; 
$database = "mydb"; 
$username = "myuser"; 
$password = "mypsw";

$link = mysql_connect( $hostname , $username , $password ) or 
        die("Attention! Connection problem with server : " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database,$link);

$Qcheck_user = "SELECT user.* 
                FROM `user`
                WHERE user.username = '$user'
￼               ￼AND user.password = '$psw' "; 

$check_user = mysql_query($Qcheck_user , $link) or
                die("Attention!Problem in selection of table user : " . mysql_error()); 

$number = mysql_num_rows( $check_user );

if ( $number == 0) 
{
    echo "Connection problem. Please try again. <br>";

    echo "<a href=\"login.php\">Πίσω</a>";

    exit;
}
else
{
    $user = mysql_fetch_array( $check_user);

    $Username = $user[0]; 
    $Name = $user["name"]; 
    $Surname = $user[3]; 
    $Email = $user["email"];


    session_register( "Username" , "Name" , "Surname" , "Email" ); 

    header("Location: home.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: Please, don't use register_globals

Comment: Can't necessarily see any guaranteed indication of register_globals here, but there are a number of SQL vulnerabilities.

Comment: This question answers itself when using Firefox or Opera :-)

Comment: @Martin What do you mean register_globals? Sorry, I am new in php and sql.

Comment: @cbuckley There's no $user nor $psw defined there

Comment: @Martin $user and $psw are defined in login.php, where is also the code: 
`<form action="check.php" method="post">
   <p><b><font face="helvetica" color="f2f2f2">Username</font></b>
   <input type="text" name="user" size="40" rows="2" maxlength="40"></p>
   <p><b><font face="helvetica" color="f2f2f2">Password</font></b>
   <input type="password" name="psw" size="40" rows="2" maxlength="40"></p>
</form>`

Comment: @felice that's why I'm talking about. Don't use [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

Comment: @Martin Do you know how can I connect these 2 variables ($user and $psw) right, between login.php and check.php? I've read what you sent, but I can't  apply it. :(

Comment: @Martin Because (i don't know if that is the problem) but now whatever username or password I use (even the right ones) I get this message: "Connection problem. Please try again."

Comment: @felice $_POST['user'], $_POST['psw']

Comment: I did this finally and it worked:
$myusername=$_POST['user']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['psw'];
Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: @Martin clearly I had too much faith here — I was hoping for the best and that they were defined properly in some other script including this one :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove these akward `￼` characters and just do this

```
$Qcheck_user = "SELECT user.* 
            FROM `user`
            WHERE user.username = '$user'
            AND user.password = '$psw' ";
```

Difference:

```
￼               ￼AND user.password = '$psw' ";
```

and

```
                 AND user.password = '$psw' ";
```

Comment: @Martin the file contains U+FFFC Object Replacement Character. They can be seen in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: @cbukley ah! In Opera, too :)

Comment: I see no difference ether. Maybe it is because of Safari. I copied @juergen d code and now the error is gone. Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have some strange characters at the beginning of:

```
￼               ￼AND user.password = '$psw' ";
```